# I always put justice now with quotes

Tags: phrases, trumpism

President Trump said "I always put justice now with quotes"
                                               -CNN

What does that mean?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82162/discussion-on-question-by-mankak-i-always-put-justice-now-with-quotes). If you have something to say, either put it in chat or write your own answer. Do not put it in comments. Comments are not for short answers.

Answer (score 5):

Trump is referring to what are more specifically called "[scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)."  In writing, we put scare quotes around a word or words to indicate that we're saying it ironically.  In speech, to intimate this same meaning, you will see people as they say the word or words do a two-handed gesture where they curl the index finger and middle finger of each hand to pantomime the appearance of quotation marks.

So what Trump means by that statement is that he believes the *Department of Justice*, which is often shortened to just *Justice* in the vernacular as a nickname, is unjust, so calling what they do "justice" is ironic.  To be clear, I'm not saying that.  I'm saying he's saying calling *Justice* "justice" is ironic.

Comment: I thought the expression was "air quotes"...?

Comment: To be fair it should be noted that many people in minorities have used "scare quotes" around the word "justice" for many decades, for reasons far more justifiable than Mr T's.

Comment: @JDM-GBG - That is an expression for the gesture, yes. The term "scare quotes" can refer to the gesture, too, but it's also what we call them when they're written, unlike "air quotes."